# Why don't the axes extend by plt.xlim(-1.5, 1.5)?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to extend the plot by `plt.xlim(-1.5, 1.5)` and `plt.ylim(-1.5, 1.5)`. Could you please explain why the the range of the plot is not as expected?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import decomposition
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
import numpy as np 

# Change the image format to svg for better quality
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'

decathlon = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/Deep-Learning/main/decathlon.txt", sep='\t')
decathlon_scaled = decathlon.copy()
decathlon_scaled.iloc[:, 0:10] = preprocessing.scale(decathlon.iloc[:, 0:10])

pca_scaled = decomposition.PCA(n_components = 10).fit(decathlon_scaled.iloc[:, 0:10])
decathlon_scaled_pca = pca_scaled.transform(decathlon_scaled.iloc[:, 0:10])
decathlon_scaled_pca_nor = decathlon_scaled_pca / np.sqrt((decathlon_scaled_pca ** 2).sum(axis = 0))
decathlon_scaled_nor = decathlon_scaled.iloc[:, 0:10] / np.sqrt((decathlon_scaled.iloc[:, 0:10] ** 2).sum(axis = 0))
decathlon_corr_circle = decathlon_scaled_pca_nor.T.dot(decathlon_scaled_nor)
decathlon_corr_circle

tmp = np.transpose(decathlon_corr_circle)[:, 0:2]
tmp = pd.DataFrame(tmp)
tmp.index = decathlon.columns[0:10]

fig = plt.figure(figsize = 1 * np.array(plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'])) # This is to have bigger plot

ax = sns.scatterplot(data = tmp,
                      x = tmp[0], y = tmp[1])

for i in range(10):
    plt.arrow(0, 0, tmp[0][i], tmp[1][i],
              color = 'orange', head_width = 0.025, length_includes_head = True)

circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 1, color='g', fill=False)
ax.add_artist(circle)

plt.xlim(-1.5, 1.5)
plt.ylim(-1.5, 1.5)
plt.axis('equal')
```

Comment: @JohanC I've just tried your suggestion, but it does not work.

Comment: @JohanC it still does not work. It does not extend the range on y-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that using [`plt.axis('equal')`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html#matplotlib-pyplot-axis) is equivalent to using `ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')`. That `adjustable='datalim'` is modifying the axis limits, even if you don't want it to.

Using the object-oriented approach for all of the last 3 lines of code is one way to solve this problem, since the default value of `adjustable` is `box`, not `datalim`. `box` means the shape of the axes will be changed to enforce the equal aspect ratio, compared to `datalim` which will keep the axes the same size, but change the axis limits. Using the state-machine version, `plt.axis('equal')`, doesn't allow you to set it to `box`, so the object-oriented approach is the best option to give you more control.

Change

```
plt.xlim(-1.5, 1.5)
plt.ylim(-1.5, 1.5)
plt.axis('equal')
```

to

```
ax.set_xlim(-1.5, 1.5)
ax.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

[image]